# Connecting data linked in a zigzag pattern

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

Is it possible to use recursive CTE to generate a link path output for the following data pattern:

| C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| C | B |
| C | D |
| E | D |
| E | F |

The desired out is separate rows representing the link path:

| L |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |
| E |
| F |

The closest I could get was using this cte:

```
with recursive links (linkval) as (
  select c1 from link_table where c1 = 'A'
  union 
  select t.c2 
  from links l
  join link_table t 
    on (t.c1 <> l.linkval or t.c2 <> l.linkval) 
) select linkval as L from links;
```

That yielded:

| L |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| D |
| F |

Comment: *The desired out is separate rows representing the link path*: what is a link path? As it stands, your resultset just shows all distinct values from both columns in the input table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer join each way and choose the non-null value:

```sql
with recursive links (linkval) as (
  select c1 from link_table where c1 = 'A'
  union 
  select coalesce(t1.c2, t2.c1)
  from links l
  left join link_table t1 on t1.c1 = l.linkval
  left join link_table t2 on t2.c2 = l.linkval
)
select linkval as L from links;
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/1NdyPCWR).